# Conditional summation in CPLEX using OPL

Tags: sum, constraints, mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl

I'm trying write in OPL this sum:

[image]

I did this, but it is not exactly what I need.

```
forall (n in cont, t in tempo, o in portos)
  sum(i in colunap, j in linhap)b[i][j][n][t] + v[n][t] == 1;
```

I should be something like, but opl does not accept it:

```
forall (n in cont[o], t in tempo[o], o in portos)
  sum(i in colunap[o], j in linhap[o])b[i][j][n][t] + v[n][t] == 1;
```

Comment: If cont and tempo depend on o then instead of forall (n in cont[o], t in tempo[o], o in portos) you d rather write forall ( o in portos,n in cont[o], t in tempo[o])

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do I declare the parameters as matrices and vectors? I tried: int H[o in 1..P-1] = ...; and range linhap=1..H[o]; but OPL does not accept it... Sorry, I'm just starting to learn OPL

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int P=3;
int H[1..P-1] = [1 , 2]; 
range linhap=1..max(o in 1..P-1) H[o];
```